# C# Get average number from rolled dice

Tags: c#, list, average

I have given an assignment where multiple random dice are rolled and the user can view the average number of the rolled dice. The only part I am having trouble with is the average part. The average part is on case 2 if you could not find since its not in English

Comment: I think i would normally be able to help but i don't speak Swedish  

Edit: But just add each tärning into a number and divide by tärningar.count()

Comment: What exactly are you “having trouble” with? Are you getting an error? Post it.

Comment: @DourHighArch, I am having trouble with finding the average number

Comment: @dementis, Yeah sorry about the Swedish part, would take a long time to change everthing to English, but thanks anyway, I will try what you are suggesting.

Comment: How would you calculate the average in 'real life'? If you know that you can translate into code.

Comment: Averages is a calculated "central" value of a set of numbers (as compared to statistical mean, mid or standard deviation for example). Calculate by adding up all the numbers on the dice, then divide by how many dice there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `break` in `case 2:` you can do something like this:

```
var average = tärningar.Average();
Console.WriteLine($"\nAverage: {average}");
```

if you don't want to use Linq, sum all values and divide them with number of rolls

```
foreach (int t in tärningar)
{
    sum += t;
}
var average = sum / tärningar.Count;
Console.WriteLine($"\nAverage: {average}");
```

Bear in mind that your random can return 0, so you should use `Random` like this:

```
int tal = slumpObjekt.Next(6) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, after writing it down, it seems did the trick, will look into what you have written closer later to see what I was missing. Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: Also if you don't want to include another add operation, you can specify the inclusive minValue and exclusive maxValue: `int tal = slumpObjekt.Next(1, 7);`